# Como deletar um documento específico de uma collection no MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

O método **remove()** usado dessa forma: db.nome_da_collection.remove(), remove todos os documents de uma collection, como eu faço pra remover um document específico?

Comment: O @GustavoMesquita posta os dados da collection que você quer remover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você quiser remover pelo id pode usar a seguinte query:

```
db.collection.remove({"_id": ObjectId("5798ffcd60b2d8a4066b482d")});
```

Você pode remover usando a mesma estrutura de um find. Por exemplo, você pode remover todos os registros que estiverem com a quantidade maior que 10.

```
db.collection.remove({quantidade : {$gt :10}})
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932928/remove-by-id-in-mongodb-console

Comment: Como eu faço para remover? Tenho que entrar na pasta da instalação e digitar o comando acima? Comigo está dizendo que este comando não é reconhecido e tal